# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException displaying when using the correct remove() method

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, concurrentmodification

I'm trying to remove an entity when isActive is false. When the entity attribute isActive is set to false, it enters if statement and removes the entity, when iterating through the entities list again after that and then crashes. From what I've researched I am using the correct way to remove an object from an array list.

the code when removing the entity and iterating through the list is

```
    for (Entity entity : entities) {// itaarate through all the entities in list of entities

        entity.render(shader, camera, this);// render each entity

        if (!entity.isActive())// checks if entity attribute is active
            entities.remove(entity);// removes entity from list

    }
```

when using the debugger after it removes the entity from the list, it goes back to the top of the for loop and then displays this page

[image]

the Variables window when debugging

[image]

the full error that displays in the console is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at project.World.render(World.java:196)
at project.Main.<init>(Main.java:152)
at project.Main.main(Main.java:167)
```

the list being  created is

```
public static ArrayList<Entity> entities; // contains all entities
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing objects in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change a collection while iterating.

```
List<Entity> entitiesToRemove = new ArrayList<>();

for (Entity entity : entities) {
    entity.render(shader, camera, this);

    if (!entity.isActive()) {
        entitiesToRemove.add(entity);
    }
}

entities.removeAll(entitiesToRemove);
```

Answer (score 3):

> `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` displaying when using the correct `remove()` method

Actually, you are using the wrong method.  Or more precisely the `remove()` method on the wrong object.

You can remove an element while iterating ... but you need to use the `remove()` method on the `Iterator` object; see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) for more details.

```
Iterator<Entity> it = entities.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Entity entity = it.next();
    entity.render(shader, camera, this);

    if (!entity.isActive()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

Note that `Iterator.remove()` is an optional operation, but `ArrayList` iterators do implement it.

The `ListIterator` API has the same method, but `Iterator` is more general.  (You can use the above sample code with any type that you can iterate with an `Iterator`, not just `List` types.)

Answer (score 0):

From  [official java list tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html):

> ```
> for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
>     if (val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next())) {
>         it.remove();
>     }
> }
> ```

Adapting the example to your code:

```
for (ListIterator<Entity> it = entities.listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    Entity entity = it.next();
    entity.render(shader, camera, this);    
    if (entity.isActive()) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```